# How do I fix the Mixpanel error "errAnonDistinctIdNonGUIDForm" in the Identify event?

Tags: mixpanel

I'm calling identify() from the Javascript API in order to merge the Mixpanel id I created previously in my custom link tracker with the user id I generate when the user signs up

Here the (redacted) JSON from the event:

```
{
  "event": "$identify",
  "properties": {
    "time": 1678441955.862,
    "distinct_id": "uEHi2oL3crDPPrrGE",
    "$anon_id": "ZT72ASHgKfPF4vMkH",
    "$browser": "Chrome",
    "$browser_version": 110,
    "$city": "xxx",
    "$current_url": "xxx",
    "$device_id": "ZT72ASHgKfPF4vMkH",
    "$failure_description": "$anon_distinct_id didn't match expected GUID pattern: ZT72ASHgKfPF4vMkH",
    "$failure_reason": "errAnonDistinctIdNonGUIDForm",
    "$had_persisted_distinct_id": true,
    "$identified_id": "uEHi2oL3crDPPrrGE",
    "$initial_referrer": "$direct",
    "$initial_referring_domain": "$direct",
    "$insert_id": "ymd3rohr1oicc2ss",
    "$lib_version": "2.45.0",
    "$mp_api_endpoint": "api-js.mixpanel.com",
    "$mp_api_timestamp_ms": 1678441958128,
    "$os": "Mac OS X",
    "$region": "xxx",
    "$screen_height": 900,
    "$screen_width": 1440,
    "$user_id": "uEHi2oL3crDPPrrGE",
    "mp_country_code": "xxx",
    "mp_lib": "web",
    "mp_processing_time_ms": 1678441958201
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Have you found a solution for it?